# cookie removing angular js not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

$scope.Logout = function () {

```
    var UsernameCookie = $cookieStore.get('Username');
    var PasswordCookie = $cookieStore.get('Password');
    console.log("logout function",PasswordCookie);
    $cookieStore.remove("Username");
    $cookieStore.remove("Password");
    UsernameCookie = "";
    PasswordCookie = "";
```

}

Comment: What is the result? Is there any error message?

Comment: no error msgs,in the console the cookie value is displayed after that  $cookieStore.remove not working that is the value stored in cookie still remain undeleted

Answer (score 1):

```
var UsernameCookie = $cookies.get('Username');
var PasswordCookie = $cookies.get('Password');
console.log("logout function",PasswordCookie);
$cookies.remove("Username");
$cookies.remove("Password");
```

Comment: Same for `get` functions

Comment: not working after changed to $cookies instead of $cookieStore,

Comment: you getting any error?? and you define $cookies in controller??

Comment: ngCookies define in your app.js??where you define your application??

Comment: yes ngCookies is defined in the js  fille along with the html index file where the cookies is stored,/and in the another page login.html the function for deleting the cookie  is called and present in the js file associated with it.both the two files the ng-cookies is defined

Comment: can i see your code?? so i will check why cookies is not removed and what is the problem